# Hide Bootstrap dismiss before loading the document

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here I am hiding the tooltip, if user clicks "close" button of bootstrap dismiss element.

When the page loads, for a second the element "#notice" is displayed. How can I hide the element before the page loads?

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
        var showstate = readCookie('showstate');
            if(showstate == 'shown')
                {
                jQuery("#notice").hide();
                }
            jQuery('#notice .close').click(function(e){
                jQuery("#notice").fadeOut();
                createCookie('showstate', 'shown');
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will load after the browser has prepared the DOM (the reason why the element shows for a second or so).

You need to set `style="display: none;"` on the element. This way the element won't be shown initially because the browser will hide it while preparing the DOM.

Then, you can use your jQuery's logic to let it remain hidden, or display it.